# How to optimize expensive objective functions with hundreds of parameters?

Tags: optimization

I have an objective function and it has more than 200 parameters to optimize. Is there any optimization method recommended for that? Is there any package that I could use for that(python would be best)?

Comment: Sorry for confusion: $\sum_{i=1}^{100}\sum_{t=1}^{3}-(y_{it}-(A_{1}y_{it-1}+A_{2}y_{it-2}+A_{3}y_{it-3}+A_{4}y_{it-4}+A_{5}y_{it-5}))^{2}$ if we have the objective function like that, how could we optimize it? Is there any package to use?

Comment: Evidently the $y_{it}$ are the "parameters."  It's a homogeneous quadratic: just set all the $y_{it}$ to zero! If instead you are varying the $A_j,$ it's an inhomogeneous quadratic: complete the square and proceed as before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your function allows for simple first and second derivatives, which can be used to implement a coordinate descent algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent

The idea is to optimize the function on each coordinate iteratively. There exists different ways to do so, such as using the gradient, or other methods. See:

> [Coordinate Descent Algorithms](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2014/12/4679.pdf)

You will need to implement it yourself, though.